# dispatch an action only on react component unmount

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I am using multiple tabs in react-js and each tab content is a component like below **profile** component that contains multiple input controls.
I want to dispatch an updateUser action when tab will be changed or component will be destroyed.

I am using useEffect, so by passing an empty dependency array ([]) to the useEffect, i can ensure that the effect runs only once when the component is mounted, and the cleanup function runs when the component is unmounted **but i want to dispatch my action only on unmount the component.**

Anyone please help me to achive this.!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../User.scss';
import iconPhone from '../../../images/icon-phone.png';
import iconMail1 from '../../../images/icon-mail-01.png';
import iconMessageTextSquare1 from '../../../images/icon-message-text-square-01.png';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../../hooks/storeHooks';
import { UserDetails } from '../model/userDetails';
import { updateUser } from '../UserSlice';
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';

const Profile: React.FC = () => {
  const [phoneExtension, setPhoneExtension] = useState('000');
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const currentUser = useAppSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
  const initialUserState = currentUser || undefined;
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserDetails | undefined>(initialUserState);
  const handleInputChange = (id: string, value: string) => {
    setUser((prevUser) => ({
      ...(prevUser as UserDetails),
      [id]: value,
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      if (currentUser && currentUser.id && user && isMounted) {
        if (!isEqual(currentUser, user)) {
          console.log('Changes detected. Dispatching update.');
          dispatch(updateUser({ id: currentUser.id, user }));
        } else {
          console.log('No changes detected.');
        }
      }
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (currentUser && currentUser.id && user) {
        if (!isEqual(currentUser, user)) {
          console.log('Changes detected. Dispatching update.');
          dispatch(updateUser({ id: currentUser.id, user }));
        } else {
          console.log('No changes detected.');
        }
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-row flex-grow profile-block'>
      <div className='card profile-card'>
        <div className='header'>
          <span className='title'>Profile</span>
          <div>update your personal and company details here.</div>
        </div>
        <div className='body'>
          <div className='profile-info'>
            <div className='protext'>
              <div className='text'>Personal info</div>
              <p>Personal details and profile picture</p>
            </div>
            <div className='card'>
              <form className='register-form'>
                <div className='form-row'>
                  <div className='form-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='firstName'>First Name:</label>
                    <input
                      type='text'
                      id='firstName'
                      className='custom-input'
                      value={user?.firstName || ''}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        handleInputChange('firstName', e.target.value);
                      }}
                      readOnly={false}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className='form-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='lastName'>Last Name:</label>
                    <input
                      type='text'
                      id='lastName'
                      className='custom-input'
                      value={user?.lastName || ''}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        handleInputChange('lastName', e.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='form-row'>
                  <div className='form-col full-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='jobtitle'>Job Title:</label>
                    <input
                      type='text'
                      id='jobtitle'
                      className='custom-input'
                      value={user?.jobTitle || ''}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        handleInputChange('jobTitle', e.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='form-row'>
                  <div className='form-col col60'>
                    <label htmlFor='phoneNumber'>Office Number</label>
                    <div className='input-group'>
                      <div className='icon-block'>
                        <img src={iconPhone} alt='icon phone' />
                      </div>
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        id='phoneNumber'
                        className='custom-input'
                        value={user?.phoneNumber || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          handleInputChange('phoneNumber', e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='form-col col40'>
                    <label htmlFor='phoneExtension'>Phone Extension:</label>
                    <input
                      type='text'
                      id='phoneExtension'
                      className='custom-input'
                      value={phoneExtension}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setPhoneExtension(e.target.value);
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div className='divider'></div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <div className='profile-info'>
            <div className='protext'>
              <div className='text'>Notification Contact Information</div>
              <p>Details here will be blah blah blah for contact information for notifications. </p>
            </div>
            <div className='card'>
              <form className='register-form'>
                <div className='form-row'>
                  <div className='form-col full-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='notifyEmail'>Notify me by email</label>
                    <div className='input-group'>
                      <div className='icon-block'>
                        <img src={iconMail1} alt='icon email' />
                      </div>
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        id='notifyEmail'
                        className='custom-input'
                        value={user?.email || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          handleInputChange('email', e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='form-col full-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='notifySms'>Notify me by sms</label>
                    <div className='input-group'>
                      <div className='icon-block'>
                        <img src={iconMessageTextSquare1} alt='icon sms' />
                      </div>
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        id='notifySms'
                        className='custom-input'
                        value={user?.phoneNumber || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          handleInputChange('phoneNumber', e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='form-col full-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='notifySms'>Notify me by dialer</label>
                    <div className='input-group'>
                      <div className='icon-block'>
                        <img src={iconMessageTextSquare1} alt='icon sms' />
                      </div>
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        id='notifySms'
                        className='custom-input'
                        value={user?.dialer || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          handleInputChange('dialer', e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='form-col full-col'>
                    <label htmlFor='notifySms'>Notify me by pager</label>
                    <div className='input-group'>
                      <div className='icon-block'>
                        <img src={iconMessageTextSquare1} alt='icon sms' />
                      </div>
                      <input
                        type='text'
                        id='notifySms'
                        className='custom-input'
                        value={user?.pager || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          handleInputChange('pager', e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with these cases is that on the one hand, you want the cleanup to run only once, but on the other hand, you can't use an empty dependencies array, because you need the updated dependencies. The solution is usually to use a ref.

**Option 1** - save the `currentUser` and the `user` on a ref:

```
// create the ref
const userRef = useRef({
  current: currentUser,
  updated: user
});

// always update the ref
useEffect(() => {
  userRef.current = {
    current: currentUser,
    updated: user
  };
});

useEffect(() => () => {
  const { current, updated } = userRef.current;

  if (current?.id && updated) {
    if (!isEqual(current, updated)) {
      console.log('Changes detected. Dispatching update.');
      dispatch(updateUser({
        id: current.id,
        user: updated
      }));
    } else {
      console.log('No changes detected.');
    }
  }
}, [dispatch, updateUser]); // you have to include the functions, but they don't change
```

**Option 2**: Use a ref to hold the state of unmounting. This ref should be updated by a cleanup function of a `useEffect` that is executed before your dispatch action effect:

```
// create the ref
const isUnmountingRef = useRef(false);

// update the ref only when unmounting
useEffect(() => () => {
  isUnmountingRef.current = true;
}, []); // empty deps

useEffect(() => () => {
  // check for unmount as well
  if (isUnmountingRef.current && currentUser?.id && user) {
    if (!isEqual(currentUser, user)) {
      console.log('Changes detected. Dispatching update.');
      dispatch(updateUser({ id: currentUser.id, user }));
    } else {
      console.log('No changes detected.');
    }
  }
}); // no depedencies
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ori, 1st Option is working for my use case. I am not sure why 2nd option is updating after every single change in any input control, but anyway 1st option is working for me and thank you so much again for helping me....!!

Comment: You're welcome. Have you you set this line `if (isUnmountingRef.current && currentUser?.id && user) {` with the 2nd option?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: And both `useEffect` have double arrow functions - `useEffect(() => () => {`?

Comment: I copied and paste the complete code, after changing any single text it is dispathing the action. Anyway i am happy with 1st option thanks a lot.